# Set preference method giving compile error as "Argument not optional" in SeleniumVBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use the `SetPreference()` method in Selenium with VBA to login to website using user details.

Below is the code.

```
Sub setttt()

    Dim driver As New ChromeDriver    
    Set driver = New ChromeDriver
    driver.Get ("https:www.gmail.com/")    
    driver.AddArgument ("--no-sandbox")      
    driver.SetPreference ("user-data-dir=C:/Users/sagar/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default")
    driver.Wait (500)

End Sub
```

I am getting a compile error

> Argument not optional

Please help if I am missing anything here.

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of other issues with your code. First, you need to set the profile of the user directory **prior** to starting Chrome. So, this would need to be set before using the `.Get()` method.

Also, if you are using `Dim .. As New` in your declaration, you do not need to `Set .. = New` later on.

Finally, instead of using `.SetPreference()` to grab your user profile, just use `.SetProfile()` with `persistent:=True`.

And I should also mention that you do not need to include `\Default` to the profile, this is included automatically; and a personal preference would be for me to use `%USERPROFILE%` instead of hard coding the username in the filepath.

```
Dim driver As New ChromeDriver

driver.SetProfile "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data", True
driver.AddArgument "--no-sandbox"
driver.Get "https://www.gmail.com/"
```

---

For your specific issue, that error code implies that you are missing a required argument. `.SetPreference` requires **two** arguments:

1. Key
2. Value

But you only provided one.

Answer (score 1):

Try remove the parentheses

```
driver.AddArgument "--no-sandbox"
```

if still not solved try with

```
driver.Get "https:www.gmail.com/"
driver.AddArgument "--no-sandbox"
driver.SetPreference "user-data-dir", "C:/Users/sagar/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default"
```